# Folder not showing up in my local directory but it is in my editor

Tags: python, visual-studio

I created a folder within a cloned repository named `GlobalMacroPy`. I added those files and created a test folder as well.

[image]

I'm trying to run the module on my command line but turns out the folder wasn't created locally, the files are there. There's just not `GlobalMacroPy` folder. NOTE: It's not `GlobalMacro`

[image]

I can't really understand why, did create a folder the wrong way?

Comment: In visual studio, if you click on the folder or a file in the folder in the solution explorer, it should appear under the panel Properties with the relative and full path of the file. Check if this is in your solution (A solution can contain files outside of the folder containing the .sln).

Comment: did you save your project?

Comment: Can you right-click and get an option for "View" or "Show" in explorer?